# rand() function in C return the same value

Tags: c

I have written a simple code with C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int val = rand();
printf("val = %d",val);
}
```

and I have written a simple bash (to compile and execute the past C programme)

```
gcc test.c
gcc -o test test.c
./test
```

the problem is when ever I execute the bash it always returns the same value :val = 1804289383
How can I make it return random values as expected ??

Comment: If you are using `bash`, an easier solution would be `echo val = $RANDOM`.

Comment: When did "a bash" come to mean a bash script? Does this usage also extend to "a sh", "a csh", "a zsh" ... can we also talk about "a dash" without getting confused?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the same starting point, repeated calls to `rand` will always generate a predictable stream of values.  The way you change this is by seeding the generator with a value which varies.  You do this by calling [srand](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand).

Assuming you don't need to run your program more than once a second, the current time would be a cheap/easy way of choosing a seed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int val = rand();
    printf("val = %d\n",val);
}
```

I've made another small change to your program.  Output is sometimes line buffered so I've added a newline `\n` character to the end of your `printf` string.

Comment: It might be helpful to add why the poster is seeing what he sees

Comment: @DennisMeng: Namely that if you don't call `srand()`, it's equivalent to calling `srand(1)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I meant more like a brief blurb on seeds and why that is related to what `rand` is doing.

Comment: @user2683768 The short answer is that using something like `srand`, you can get different starting points, and hence you will not keep spewing the same stream of numbers.

Comment: @user2683768 rand() is not random, but [pseudorandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom) and `srand` sets starting point.

Comment: Note that with the code shown (using `time()` to seed `srand()`) if you run the program a few times in a row during a single second, you'll get the same results.  Look into sub-second timing, or process IDs, or get a real random number from `/dev/random` or ...